# Simplifying the statement using logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwiZx.png)

Here is what I have tried:

1. From my textbook, I have learned about the precedence of logical operators. It says to deal with negations first.
2. If we were to do the negations first, I end up with:

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAGIx.png)

3. And from here on out I'm kind of lost on what to do next

Comment: Expand the expression using the facts that $(a \wedge b) \vee c \Leftrightarrow (a \vee c) \wedge (b \vee c)$ and $(a \vee b) \wedge c \Leftrightarrow (a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)$.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice. The final answer I came up with is  (r ∨ p) after applying the identity laws. Can anyone confirm I have done this right?